# Get the template of a funtion app in azure

Tags: azure-rm-template

I'm trying to export the template of a function app. All i managed to get is the full JSON template of the resource group the function app belongs to.

The automation script link below generates it. Even if i'm located in function app settings, it keeps generating the full resource group template.

[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except that you can export the template from the resource group, you can export the template from the deployment. Find the function related **deployment name** from your **resource group** page-**settings**-**developments**, then click Templates and Download.

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [export an Azure Resource Manager template from existing resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template#view-template-from-deployment-history).

Alternatively, you can access the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) site to discover the Azure Resource Management APIs, navigate to the resources you are looking for, and just copy\paste it.